# Show/hide div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#viewAll').hide(); 
                $('#viewProductIframe').hide(); 
                $('#viewIngredientIframe').hide(); 
            $('#viewPackagingIframe').hide(); 

            $.viewMap = {
                'viewEmpty' : $('#viewEmpty'),
                'viewAll' : $('#viewAll'),
                'viewProductIframe' : $('#viewProductIframe'),
                'viewIngredientIframe' : $('#viewIngredientIframe'),
                'viewPackagingIframe' : $('#viewPackagingIframe')
            };

            $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
                // hide all
                $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
                // show current
                $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
            }); 
        });
```

It should show/hide a set of divs. Only the `viewProductIframe` div actually appears.
At first I had 4 divs without iframes showing tables from a database. I put the content of these divs into "viewAll" and added the "viewProductIframe" and the other two. 
This change apparently broke the code and I can't find the reason.

My dropdown menu:

```
<select name="viewSelector" id="viewSelector">
                        <option name="viewEmpty" value="viewEmpty">Select an Option</option>
                        <option name="viewAll" value="viewAll">All</option>
                        <option name="viewProductIframe" value="viewProductIframe">Products</option>
                        <option name="viewIngredientIframe" value="viewIngredientIframe">Ingredients</option>
                        <option name="viewPackagingIframe" value="viewPackagingIframe">Packaging</option>
                    </select>
```

The only div that shows up:

```
<div id="viewProductIframe" name="viewProductIframe">
                    <h2>Product</h2>
                    <iframe src="products.php" class="displayFrame" />
                </div>
```

Another iframe div, remains invisble:

```
<div id="viewIngredientIframe" name="viewIngredientIframe">
                        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
                        <iframe src="ingredients.php" class="displayFrame" />
                    </div>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks, I honestly didn't see that. Accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

1) set common class for all divs i added class `common` for example

```
<div id="viewProductIframe" name="viewProductIframe" class="common">
                    <h2>Product</h2>
                    <iframe src="products.php" class="displayFrame" />
                </div>

 <div id="viewIngredientIframe" name="viewIngredientIframe" class="common">
                    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
                    <iframe src="ingredients.php" class="displayFrame" />
                </div>
```

jquery be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".common").hide();
    $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
                    $(".common").hide(); // hide all divs
                     var id = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); // get current val
                    $("#" + id).show() // show current div id
      }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but the only thing that changed is that the product iframe (the only one that showed before) is now visible when I open the page. I tried to look at Chrome's error console but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: put  `$(".common").hide();` call in outside also. I updated my code check i hope it works what you expect

Comment: That hides the divs, thanks. :) But selecting the menu options still doesn't show them.

Comment: Well thank you for trying to help me, but the issue wasn't with the jQuery at all - `<iframe .. />` doesn't work. It broke all the following divs ... I changed it to `<iframe></iframe>`. Your code works perfectly.